# How can my mysql before update trigger iterate through a table's column names and get OLD/NEW.column_name values?

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a before update trigger in MySQL to automatically log any change done to *employees* table in the *sys_logs* table.

Now, since I wouldn't know in which column(s) the change is done, I want to store the changes in a string (Simulating JSON). To do so, I'm using a cursor within the trigger, that gets the columns from *information_schema*, and then accessing OLD and NEW virtual tables, as you can see in the snippet below

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER before_update_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE col_nam VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE jost VARCHAR(700) DEFAULT "";
    
    
    DECLARE columns_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT iss.COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS iss
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'employees';
        
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET counter = -1;
    
    OPEN columns_cursor;
        SET jost = '"{';
        loop_columns: LOOP
            
            FETCH columns_cursor INTO col_nam;
            
            IF counter = -1 THEN
                LEAVE loop_columns;
            END IF; 
            
            IF OLD.col_nam != NEW.col_nam THEN
                SET jost = CONCAT(jost, '"',col_nam, '": {"Old Value": "',OLD.col_nam,', "New Value": "',NEW.col_nam,'"}, ');
            END IF;
            
            SET jost = CONCAT(jost, '"}"');
        
        END LOOP;
        
    CLOSE columns_cursor;
    
    INSERT INTO sys_logs (details) VALUES (jost);
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

I'm getting an unknown column error stating that `col_nam` is not in OLD or NEW. I've tried changing delimiters, wrapping `col_nam` between back ticks, but no luck.

[image]

I'm fairly new to MySQL Triggers and procedures, so if there is a better way of doing this, and you can share some documentation, I'd be grateful; so far I haven't found anything useful that does not involve using an external programming language.

If not possible, should I hardcode the column names in the trigger?

Thanks!

Comment: You would need dynamic sql to set a column name from code, but dynamic sql is not allowed in triggers. You must hard code the column names.

Comment: The linked question is the best solution I know of. Don't use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA query in the trigger, instead use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA query to _generate_ the code for the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, with hard-coded column names. If you ever add or drop the columns of that table, you must re-generate the trigger.

Comment: Also don't use `CONCAT()` to create JSON documents. Use the builtin [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html).

Comment: For tracking data changes, you should consider one of the audit log plugins, that would be a lot easier to manage instead of triggers.